# How can I define a style for all items in a parent element without CSS

Tags: html

I am building a simple webpage in a platform where I am restricted to changing CSS styles in html tags using the `style` attribute.

Now, in a Definition list, I would like to increase the bottom padding for all `dd` elements, but without having to add a `style` attribute to every single `dd` element. Is that possible, and if so: how?

For example, starting from:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>- black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>- white cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

I would like to increase padding for the `dd` elements:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd style="padding-bottom: 10pt">- black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd style="padding-bottom: 10pt">- white cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

But I would prefer to change the CSS styling only once. I would probably need to do this in the `dl` element, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Simply, no. You should use JavaScript in case if change in css file is not allowed.

Comment: if he can use javascript, he should also be able to write css somewhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend this b/c it's not the correct way to style but it will work.  In your html page, create a style block like this:

```
<style>
    dd {
        padding-bottom: 10pt;
    }
</style>
```

Another way is to add a class to the parent dl and style the dd from there.

```
<style>
    .blah dd{
        padding-bottom: 10pt;
    }
</style>
```

and in your html do do this:

```
<dl class="blah">
    <dt>Coffee</dt>
    <dd>- black hot drink</dd>
    <dt>Milk</dt>
    <dd>- white cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: The very first paragraph of the question says that they cannot use style elements.

Comment: Correct, but it sounded like he was restricted to not editing the css file not creating a styling block inside his html page.

Comment: @SariRahal Thanks, this works. You a re right that I can add styling blocks, although they might be removed again by the site editor...
You say that this is "not the correct way". Is this because it is better to edit the CSS file, or is there another reason?

Comment: You are correct.  The best way is to edit the css file and include that into your page.  In-line styling and styling blocks are accepted but are harder to maintain.  In the long run will cause you technical dept to maintain.  Simple spending time looking for styling and changing in multiple places will become tedious.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible

No.

A style attribute can only affect the element to which it is applied.

The exception if when a child element has `inherit` as the value for the property you are changing. This is not the default case for `padding`.